# sum of seires $\sum_{k=j}^\infty\frac{1}{k^{p}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

For any positive integer $j$ and real number $p>1$, we know that the series
$$\sum_{k=j}^\infty\frac{1}{k^{p}}$$ converges, how to get the upper bound of the series which is determined by $j$?  I remember in a paper it is $C(p)(j^{1-p})$, where $C(p)$ is a function of $p$ but I don't remember the exact form of $C(p)$. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Almost from definition $$\sum_{k=j}^\infty\frac{1}{k^{p}}=\zeta (p,j)$$ where appears the [Hurwitz zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function).

If $j=1$, it reduces to $\zeta (p)$ which is  the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).

For a bound, you may consider that $$\sum_{k=j}^\infty\frac{1}{k^{p}}<\zeta (p)$$ and, for even integer values of $p$, the values are known. The next table shows some of them 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & \frac{\pi ^2}{6} \\
 4 & \frac{\pi ^4}{90} \\
 6 & \frac{\pi ^6}{945} \\
 8 & \frac{\pi ^8}{9450} \\
 10 & \frac{\pi ^{10}}{93555} \\
 12 & \frac{691 \pi ^{12}}{638512875} \\
 14 & \frac{2 \pi ^{14}}{18243225} \\
 16 & \frac{3617 \pi ^{16}}{325641566250} \\
 18 & \frac{43867 \pi ^{18}}{38979295480125} \\
 20 & \frac{174611 \pi ^{20}}{1531329465290625}
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thank you. Is there any upper bound which is determined by $j$? I remember in a paper it is $C(p)(j^{1-p})$, where $C(p)$ is a function of $p$ but I don't remember the exact form of $C(p)$.